# How do I parse information from a command after a particular word

Tags: sed, command-line, cut

I get information from the `gpstate -s` command and it prints with debug info that I would like to remove. There is one line in particular that I would like to save, the `Master Host` line. I need the value for master host (I changed this to HostName) so that I can store it as an environmental variable.

```
20210805:00:02:22:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Obtaining Segment details from master...
20210805:00:02:22:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Gathering data from segments...
20210805:00:02:23:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-----------------------------------------------------
20210805:00:02:23:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:--Master Configuration & Status
20210805:00:02:23:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-----------------------------------------------------
20210805:00:02:23:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-   Master host                    = HostName
20210805:00:02:23:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-   Master postgres process ID     = 5000
20210805:00:02:23:025334 gpstate:HostName:gpadmin-[INFO]:-   Master data directory          = /data/master/gpseg-1
```

I tried using `gpstate -s | sed -n -e 's/^.*Master\sHost //p'` for getting everything after from Master Host and further, but that gave me empty results. I was going to use the `cut` command after `sed` in order to get the HostName.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `Master\sHost` in your sed script, there are 2 reason why that might've failed:

1. The input has `host` starting with a lower case `h` so `Host` won't match that,
2. `\s` is a shorthand only supported by GNU sed, use `[[:space:]]` in
   a POSIX sed or `[ \t]` in any sed.

You can use `awk`:

```bsh
$ gpstate -s | awk -F'= ' '/Master host/ { print $2 }' 
HostName
```

With `sed`:

```bsh
$ gpstate -s | sed -n '/Master host/s/.*= //p'
HostName
```

Comment: Thank you this was the answer I was looking for!